# How can i print gridview Duplex in C# - devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to print gridview in duplex i tried the code shown below. but  this line show me error `XtraReport1 r = new XtraReport1();`. How can i make it work when printing gridView? 
i get

> CS0246: The type or namespace name `XtraReport1' could not be found.
>   Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

[image]

```
    private void btnPrintPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            XtraReport1 r = new XtraReport1();
            r.PrintingSystem.StartPrint += new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintDocumentEventHandler(PrintingSystem_StartPrint);
            r.ShowPreview();
        }

        private void PrintingSystem_StartPrint(object sender, DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintDocumentEventArgs e) {
            e.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.Duplex = System.Drawing.Printing.Duplex.Horizontal;
        }
```

Comment: How 'bout you post the actual error or better yet google the error.

Comment: Maybe `XtraReport r = new XtraReport();`?

Comment: @LarsTech yes i get `CS0246: The type or namespace name `XtraReport1' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?` error

Comment: @user6144226 i added the error

Comment: You need to include the assembly/add the correct using to the namespace where you defined your XtraReport1

Comment: That's not what I typed.  I removed the "1" from the declaration.

Comment: i tried that but doesn't print anything i get `The document doesnt found any page`

Comment: May be printing Grid view and Report is different?

Comment: If XtraReport1 is already declared, then you don't have to make a new one.  Replace the "r" with "XtraReport1".  Only add that StartPrint event once, in the form's constructor or through the designer.

Comment: @LarsTech I am not sure if i understand you very well you mean like this `XtraReport.PrintingSystem.StartPrint += new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintDocumentEventHandler(PrintingSystem_StartPrint);
            r.ShowPreview();`

Comment: i want to print gridview1, i used `gridView1.ShowPrintPreview();` before which working fine but cant add duplex functionality to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through documentation:
[How to: Print a Grid and Show its Print Preview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3230/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Examples/Export-and-Printing/How-to-Print-a-Grid-and-Show-its-Print-Preview)
[How to: Customize Print Settings When Printing GridControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/11543/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Examples/Export-and-Printing/How-to-Customize-Print-Settings-When-Printing-GridControl)
[Preset PrinterSettings](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q139325/preset-printersettings)
[Get/Set PageSettings and PrinterSettings to XtraReports reconized by preview and print](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q237147/get-set-pagesettings-and-printersettings-to-xtrareports-reconized-by-preview-and-print)

1. To print the grid control, you should use either the
   [GridControl.Print](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.Print.method) or [GridControl.ShowPrintPreview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.ShowPrintPreview.method) methods.
2. Then handle the [BaseView.PrintInitialize](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView.PrintInitialize.event) event to customize print settings.

See this example which let you know that how access printing events for further customization:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    sqlDataSource1.Fill();

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridControl1.Print();
}

private void gridView1_PrintInitialize(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.PrintInitializeEventArgs e)
{
    PrintingSystemBase pb = e.PrintingSystem as PrintingSystemBase;
    pb.StartPrint -= pb_StartPrint;
    pb.StartPrint +=pb_StartPrint;


}

void pb_StartPrint(object sender, PrintDocumentEventArgs e)
{
    e.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.Duplex = System.Drawing.Printing.Duplex.Horizontal;
    //e.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
    e.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Foxit Reader PDF Printer";

}
```

Comment: Thank you. the documentation doesn't say anything about print gridcontrol in duplex.

Comment: @user8066749:update my answer, Now you can access printer settings on start_print event.. Hope this help you..